# Data Flow between two different react application

Tags: reactjs

I have developed a react application in a modular way. Such that every module is an independent application. I need to pass the data from one route from application one to other routes on application 2.
The data that I need to pass is large in size.

Requesting the approach apart from window.location .
All of my applications are deployed on the same server on Linux.

Comment: Can you try creating a wrapper react application enclosing all react applications to pass data from one react application to another or sharing data among other things. This way if you want you could have a common store for all applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is to create a store that all of the routes have access to. If you were to use redux for example, you can keep `sharedValue: ''` in a root reducer. Then use `mapStateToProps` to each individual component for those routes.

Here is an example reducer.

```
function rootReducer(state = {sharedValue: ''}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SHARED_VALUE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        sharedValue : action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And example routes.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}/>
<Route path="path1" component={Component1}/>
<Route path="path2" component={Component2}/>
```

And, depending on how you want the components to receive the `sharedValue`, you can use `mapStateToProps` to share `sharedValue` with the components.

Component1

```
// Component1.js
// put the below outside of the component

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { sharedValue } = state
  return { sharedValue  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component1)
```

Component2

```
// Component2.js
// put the below outside of the component

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { sharedValue } = state
  return { sharedValue  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component2)
```

There is more to setting up redux but here you can see how both components have access to the shared value. Since it is in a shared store, the value should persist across both routes.